# Coordinate Conversion of Arrays with Different Length

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates

I'm trying to convert between coordinate systems for two set of 1D arrays. I know how to make this particular conversion if both 1D arrays had the same length, but that is not the case, as seen below:

```
y = np.linspace(0,360, 90)

x = np.linspace(2,90,22)
```

The overall goal is to create a meshgrid out of the new set of arrays, but getting to that point seems to be rather challenging. I've initially tried using two `for` loops that enumerates from 0 to 89, and then from 0 to 21, but that was a dead end.

Comment: Please provide a small example of what you mean because your question is a bit unclear. Do you just want a meshed grid using `np.meshgrid()`? If you are converting the grid of data you have to interpolate the data to the new grid ...

Comment: Does `np.meshgrid(y,x)` do anything useful?  Experiment with smaller arrays, say, 3 and 4 elements long so you can display all values.

Comment: I'm familiar with meshgrid. What I'm trying to do is a straight coordinate conversion, from latitude and longitude to Cartesian for example. I have function that does the conversion into the coordinates I want, but requires the arrays to be of equal lengths. I'll try using smaller arrays, as suggested to see if I get anywhere

Comment: Are they required to be equal length because you have to have a Lat and Lon to do the transformation....?